# understanding dtype in theano

Tags: python, neural-network, theano

I am new to theano , an am trying to reproduce result for [this](https://github.com/mbeissinger/intro_deep/blob/master/MLP_theano.ipynb) code on my local machine. When I run the code as it is I get following error when I run the theano functions(In [48]) `f_train` and `f_test`.

> TypeError: ('An update must have the same type as the original shared variable (shared_var=b_y, shared_var.type=TensorType(float32, vector), update_val=Elemwise{sub,no_inplace}.0, update_val.type=TensorType(float64, vector)).', 'If the difference is related to the broadcast pattern, you can call the tensor.unbroadcast(var, axis_to_unbroadcast[, ...]) function to remove broadcastable dimensions.')

When I change the line:

```
b_y = numpy.zeros(shape=(10,), dtype="float32")
```

to

```
b_y = numpy.zeros(shape=(10,), dtype=theano.config.floatX)
```

then it runs fine. Now in my `.theanorc` I have `floatX = float32`. I am not able to understand why this is happening.

Moreover if I change all `dtype=theano.config.floatX` to `dtype="float32"`, then also I get the same error.

Please help me understand what is going on here.

Comment: Have you verified that your `.theanorc` is in the right place and is actually getting loaded?

Comment: It is in my home directory.If I am not mistaken , that is where it is supposed to be. I am using Mac OX

Comment: I am not sure how to check if it is being loaded properly.

Comment: What output do you get if you do `print theano.config.floatX` or `print repr(theano.config.floatX)`?

Comment: `float32` for first one and `'float32'` for second print command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your environment is somehow messed up.  Without going into your environment details, I cannt give you a better solution; but whenever I have such issues, I always go for that code environment's command line flags.  You can set the flags for Theano when you run the code on the command line like this:

```
THEANO_FLAGS='floatX=float32,device=gpu0'  python <myscript>.py
```

More here: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html

Hope that helps.